# Disable Chrome 69 autofill

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

I've been struggling with Chrome password autofilling for a while a couple days ago, back when I was using Chrome 69.

I finally fixed the problem by removing the id and the name from my password input because autocomplete="off" or autocomplete="new-password" were getting ignored by Chrome.

I updated my browser to v69 this morning and boom, the autocomplete is on again, my workarounds are not disabling it anymore, and I can't find anything about this on the net.
Also tried jQuery disableAutofill plugin without success.

EDIT: This is for a website used by several users and I can't tell them to go to chrome settings and disable autofill. I need a html or js solution

Maybe someone has a good solution?

Thanks

Comment: Have you try delete cache in Browser option?

Comment: Not working, chrome still suggests me to use the registered password

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to open your Chrome browser and open the main menu (three vertical dots) to find the Settings option.

1. When the drop-down menu appears, click Settings. You can also type
   the following text into Chrome's address bar in place of clicking on
   this menu item: chrome://settings. Under People, select Payment
   methods.
2. Toggle the slider to the right of Autofill forms to the Off
   position. To re-enable the feature at any time, repeat this process
   and click the slider to move it to the On position.

[image](http://prntscr.com/ktvlvz)

Comment: I need it to be in my code, I got several users and I can't tell them to do this.

Comment: You will probably need to create a 2 input field and hide them .
<input type="hidden" name="username"/>
<input type="hidden" name="password"/>

or 

<input type="text" name="username" style="display:none"/>
<input type="password" name="password" style="display:none"/>

When you do this, even though chrome tries to auto-fill the form , it actually fills the hidden input field with name [username and password]. I have faced this issue before and this solved my issue. 
Hope this helps